# AWS S3 via proxy using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy

I am trying to get the object image via proxy server using PHP.

I am using this code

```
 $client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'us-east-1',
        'request.options' => array(
        'proxy' => '127.0.0.1:123'
        ),
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => base64_decode(KEY),
            'secret' => base64_decode(SECRET)
        ]
    ]);
```

which seems working fine.  Now, i am not sure if proxy server is used or not.

I have no clue regarding this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a proxy with S3Client yet but in my experience any PHP- or Console-based applications supporting proxies will always use a proxy if one is stated. The easiest way to find out in your case if the proxy was used is by

- temporarily shutting down the proxy server that you are using in your code (if that is possible) **or** to block access to it using outbound firewall access rules on your PHP server or inbound rules on the proxy
- re-running the above code and check if you are still able to access AWS

You may also use the S3Client's [`stats`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#stats) and [`debug`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#debug) flags to get more information about the underlying HTTP connections which should also show connections to the proxy rather than direct connections to AWS:

```
$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-east-1',
    'debug'       => TRUE, // enable debug info
    'stats'       => TRUE, // enable stats
    'request.options' => array(
    'proxy' => 'http://127.0.0.1:123' // add the protocol before the IP address
    ),
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => base64_decode(KEY),
        'secret' => base64_decode(SECRET)
    ]
]);

// Perform an operation.
$result = $client->listBuckets();
// Inspect the stats.
$stats = $result['@metadata']['transferStats'];
// display all information about last transfer
print_r($stats);
```

Comment: what is 'request.options' => array(
    'proxy' => '127.0.0.1:123'
    ), here.  any purpose ?

Comment: Also do we need to right the code at proxy server ? or main server ?

Comment: @MandeepSingh I took your code and extended it with the mentioned flags so you should know what it does. It simply advises the requesting server - your web server - to not directly access AWS but to send the requests to the given server. Have a look at the [`proxy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#proxy) information on the AWS SKD for more info.

Comment: When i am trying to connect via proxy, the script is returning error "AWS HTTP error: cURL error 56: Received HTTP code 302 from proxy after CONNECT". Not able to figure out this.

Comment: @MandeepSingh it may be due to an incorrect proxy value (no protocol stated, add "http://" in front of the IP). [Another Q&A](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=86627) on the AWS Developer Forum suggests that the parameters may be send as GET rather than POST but this does not apply to your posted code - are we perhaps missing some code from your side?

Comment: @MandeepSingh were you able to solve your problem? If so, could you add your solution to your question and mark it as an answer? This might also help somebody else! If my answer helped you solve it, feel free to mark it as an answer :-)

Comment: '@SaschaM78' this still not solved, Client told me to hold this feature.